# Rechargeable Batteries

Tags: sound, equipment, location, power, battery

Was looking for any good recommendations on reliable power/battery solutions.

Working on set, Location Sound and other equipment can soup up the power as many of you may know.

I've tried the 15min Vatrta AA/AAA quick charger. Works quite well for emergency recharging. But was also looking for 9v reliable recharger (lectrosonic Radio Mics especially)

There are many on the market, but was wondering if anyone has any reliable products. I don't mind to pay for decent reliable ones, because I know there are lots of cheap alternatives to steer away from..

Any recommendations would be gratefully received.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/battery-options-for-your-recording-rig?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With AAs and AAAs, go with the MAHA Powerex chargers. They give you a lot more control that'll give you a better lifespan from your batteries. Avoid quick charging as much as possible. Instead of quick charging, buy more batteries for standby.
http://www.mahaenergy.com/chargers/

The iPower 9Vs are the standard for location sound guys. They come with their own charger but you can get other online. Just be careful and read the specs of what you are buying. It's pretty easy to bloat or kill a 9v. I use the Soshine 9vs as well. Great lifespan but there's a QC problem where not all of them that you order will be good. But even with the duds, they have still been a cheaper option to the iPowers.

http://jwsoundgroup.net/index.php?/topic/8218-600-mah-rechargable-9v-batteries-anyone-tried-them-yet/page-2

Google the jwsound forums. They are a much better source of information on location sound matters.

Comment: Thanks for the advice mate, much appreciated and very helpful!

Comment: Not worth a separate answer, but agree with takuya. iPower 9V's are amazing, but I'm now having better luck with the black Sanyo Eneloops than the Powerex's (I have dozens of each). They definitely hold a charge for longer in storage, which can be handy.

Answer (score 2):

for AA go with Eneloop (originally Sanyo now Panasonic) and slow charging of 4+ hours. If you'd like to research other low-self-discharge NiMH models, please share your findings.

Comment: Yeah Eneloop, ive used before for AA/AAA and they were actually pretty good.. I'll continue the research, thanks for your reply bud!